# sonarqube 4.0 preview analysis (local)

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, software-quality

I want to throw preview analysis (local) with eclipse sonar plugin and remote sonarqube 4.0.

What information transfer between eclipse and remote sonarqube 4.0? That preview or local analysis could be pass only profile rules and process is only local?

Thank you,

Regards,

Comment: What is your actual problem? Sonar runs on server (9000 default) and you can browse via browser or you have to connect with eclipse.

Comment: My main problem is sonarqube server 4.0 with eclipse plugin. I want to migrate pmd plugin eclipse to pmd sonar plugin eclipse. I have 350 users-eclipse in projects that need throw rules locally before commit. I don't want to migrate if produce server down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In preview mode the code violations (or issues) won't be updated in the remote SonarQube server. It only creates a JSON report into the SonarQube working directory (`.sonar` as default). The Eclipse plugin always connects to the remote, so you cannot see the preview results in Eclipse.

But you can make a report from the JSON with the [SonarQube Isse Report plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues+Report+Plugin).

Comment: Creates a json report in filesystem of server SonarQube? Thx

Comment: @user3815289, the SonarQube Runner makes the report so it will be on the machine that analyse the source. Of course it can be the same. I usually run the analyses and the webserver on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SonarLint tool to preview analysis.

> SonarLint is an extension to your favorite IDE that provides on-the-fly feedback to developers on new bugs and quality issues injected into their code.

http://www.sonarlint.org